# Angular: Bind observable and evalute results

Tags: angular, observable, bind

I want to have structure like

```
MyStruc {
   action2Execute:any; // see #q3

   constructor(coll: CollectionServices) {
    // see #q1
   }
}
```

and have a ServiceClass like

```
MyServiceClass {
  constructor(public http: HttpClient) { }

  myHTTPRequest(id:number):Observable<boolean>{
     this.http.get<boolean>('call/my/webservice/'+id)
  }
}
```

and a Controller class like

```
MyControllerClass {

  constructor(private coll: CollectionServices) {}
  ...
  execHTTP() {
     new MyStruc(coll).action2Execute.apply(1);
  }

}
```

Now my purpose is to bind `action2Exectue` to the method `myHTTPRequest`, call  it and process the results. I have two problems with this

1. If I set `action2Execute` like `this.action2Execute=coll.myHTTPRequest`  than I have the problem when I call it in `MyControllerClass.#execHTTP()` I get an error which says:
   `TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined` ==> `http` is `undefined`
2. My other problem is that by just using `apply` I do not get the results from the observable, i.e. from the HTTP request.
3. What type should have `action2Exectue` in the class `MyStruc`?

Comment: What is the purpose of the MyStruc class? You can make it static so you can execute methods without an instance but I don't see why you're not doing the work in the service

Comment: The purpose of `MyStruc` is that I have several states for an item, e.g. message. On the state `INBOX` I have several labels and an action - which applies only for the state `INBOX`. While for e.g. `DRAFT` I have a different set of labels and actions. Since I know in advance which actions to which exectued functions I wanted to assign them all at once and use them in `MyControllerClass` which does the further handling of the results - which is somehow similar. More clear?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out how to declare it:

```
MyStruc {
   action2Execute:((id:number) => Observable<any>);

   constructor(coll: CollectionServices) {
     // to bind it to the Service ...
     this.action2Execute=coll.myHTTPRequest.bind(coll);
   }
}
```

than I can call it as expected just as a regular Observable:

```
MyControllerClass {
...
 constructor(private coll: CollectionServices) {}
  ...
  execHTTP() {
     new MyStruc(coll).action2Execute(1).subscribe(res => console.log(res));
  }
}
```